# how to make this raw sql to django orm

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I wanna change below raw sql code to Django ORM.
How can I do?

```
SELECT ad_id, count(distinct(user_id))
FROM reachcount
GROUP BY ad_id;
```

I did like this

```
queryset = ReachCount.objects.values('ad_id').annotate(Count('user_id',distinct=True))
```

but it's not the result what I want. So I checked raw sql code with querset.query. below code is the raw code

```
SELECT `test_reachcount`.`ad_id`, COUNT(DISTINCT `test_reachcount`.`user_id`) AS `user_id__count` 
FROM `test_reachcount` 
GROUP BY `test_reachcount`.`ad_id`, `test_reachcount`.`user_id` 
ORDER BY `test_reachcount`.`ad_id` ASC, `test_reachcount`.`user_id` ASC
```

if I get rid of "`test_reachcount`.`user_id`" in group by clause. 
I think this code is similar what I want.

let's summarize about question.

1. Why did `test_reachcount`.`user_id` add automatically?
2. How can I get rid of `test_reachcount`.`user_id` code.
3. if you make code better. plz share me.

Thank you for reading long question.

My model is like this

```
class ReachCount(models.Model):
    ad_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    reg_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering=['ad_id','user_id']
```

I attach my sample data.

ad_id  user_id

1      Aiza
2      Aiza
3      Aiza
4      Aiza
1      andre
2      andre
3      andre
4      andre
1      andre
1      andre
1      bonita
2      bonita
3      bonita
2      bonita
2      byun12
3      byun12
4      edward
5      edward
1      gallop
3      gallop
4      gallop
7      gallop
3      gallop10
6      gallop10
8      gallop99
2      jihoonpark1
5      jihoonpark1
6      jihoonpark1
5      rhewster
6      rhewster
7      rhewster
2      toto
4      toto
9      toto
10      Aiza
10      andre

Comment: test_reachcount seems like your table name. Should not alter the effect of your sql stmt, I think if you need to do a count(distinct), you need to have that variable in group by also. Otherwise it does not make sense.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, the results you expect and what you get?

Comment: I attached sample data.

Comment: test_reachcount is my table name. variable group by??? I don't get it Can you explain detail. and What part doesn't it make sense?

Comment: For your sample data, I am getting identical results from django and SQL

Comment: What version of Django are you using? My query is SELECT "app_test1"."ad_id", COUNT(DISTINCT "app_test1"."user_id") AS "user_id__count" FROM "app_test1" GROUP BY "app_test1"."ad_id". In Django print(Test1.objects.values('ad_id').annotate(Count('user_id', distinct=True)).query)

Comment: it's django 1.10.2 version. python3.5 
and I tested again. my django don't work like you. What version of django are you using?

Comment: Django 1.8. What does your model look like?

Comment: ok attacked my model at question

Comment: oh thank you.. @sureshvv
I get rid of meta code in my model class. and It's work that I want.
Really thank you.
it's ordering problem. I didn't know why ordering affect the sql.